# Update entites 1-1 Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
    public async Task SaveAsync(Cliente cliente)
    {
        if (cliente.Id == Guid.Empty)
        {
            _cadastroContext.Clientes.Add(cliente);
        }
        else
        {
            _cadastroContext.Clientes.Update(cliente);
        }

        await _cadastroContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

The Cliente class has a 1-1 relationship with the Conta class, when I save a new record, both classes are saved simultaneously, but when I go to update it is not updated to the Conta class.

After the Update command is executed, the properties of the Conta class are the same as those in the database and not the same as those sent.

How can I make two composite classes update?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Do not include any screenshot of your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to `include` the conta objects before updating the clientes object.

```cs
public async Task SaveAsync(Cliente cliente) 
{
    ... code ommited for brevity
    else 
    {
        var savedCliente = _cadastroContext.Include(c => c.Conta).FirstOrDefault(c = c.Id == cliente.Id);
        savedCliente = cliente;

        _cadastroContext.Update(savedCliente);
        await _cadastroContext.SaveChangesAsync()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, This code worked for me, however I needed to use AsNoTracking().